# Add IValidator to ListBinding for JFace Databinding

Tags: java, jface

The class `ValueBinding` has two `UpdateValueStrategy` (for target to model and model to target) which both have a converter and three validators ("after get", "after convert" and "before set").

The `ListBinding` with its `UpdateListStrategy`s has nothing of the sort, only a converter (and I'm not sure if that thing is even on). I want to implement something similar to the `UpdateValueStrategy`'s validators for the use case of validating that there is at least one element in the list.

What I tried (and how I failed):

- override `ListBinding.doUpdate(...)` - it's private
- add a change listener to `ListBinding.validationStatusObservable` and validate after it was set - I can't tell if the update was model -> target or target -> model, so I don't know which list should be validated

What works is creating a second binding against a new `WritableValue` and add a validator to that. But that's not really optimal. I'd rather have a binding that won't update when the validation fails.

I'm sure someone must have had the same problem before, hence the question: How do I add a `IValidator` to a `ListBinding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made my own `UpdateListStrategy` (with blackjack and... nevermind):

```
public class BetterUpdateListStrategy extends UpdateListStrategy {

    @Override
    protected IStatus doAdd(IObservableList observableList, Object element, int index) {
        IStatus result = super.doAdd(observableList, element, index);
        if (result.isOK()) {
            result = validate(observableList);
        }
        return result;
    }

    // these methods are overridden in exactly the same way: 
    // protected IStatus doMove(IObservableList observableList, int oldIndex, int newIndex)
    // protected IStatus doRemove(IObservableList observableList, int index) 
    // protected IStatus doReplace(IObservableList observableList, int index, Object element) 

    private IStatus validate(IObservableList value) {
        // my validation; I added an IValidator to have a similar API
        // to the UpdateValueStrategy
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
}
```

It's not yet working perfectly (the binding does not have an error status if the validation fails), but this might help someone else.